# Why do we need Polymer Observer if two-way bindng will work?

Tags: polymer

According to [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers), it observes all changes to Polymer properties.

But, two-way binding (using {{}}) already does that, right? Why do we need observer to process the changes?

Answer (score 3):

They are similar in that a value-change invokes the effects of both an observer and data binding, but they have different purposes.

#### Two-way data binding

- A two-way data binding is an annotation
- Sets a property of element `A` to the value of another property in element `B`
- Any changes to `B`'s property automatically update `A`'s property, and vice versa

#### Observer

- An observer is a function that is called whenever a value-change occurs to one or more properties

  - **Example:** To set an element's operational mode based on the value of its `enabled` property
- An observer's purpose is not necessarily to set another property (unlike data bindings). It could call another function based on the new property value.

  - **Example:** To generate an AJAX request when a `url` property changes
- The observed properties must be in a single element (e.g., a parent element cannot observe a child's property without binding it to its own copy of the property)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got both of them mixed up.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <paper-input value="{{myValue}}">
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    is:"my-element",
    properties:{
      myValue:{
        type:String
      }
    }
  </script>
 </dom-module>
```

`value="{{myValue}}"` can be read as whenever there is any change **value**, **myValue** will also get updated.

Now, consider a scenario where you want to be informed whenever `myValue` changes. Above written code is not enough for that (yes, i know you can listen on `value-changed` event to know about the change, we'll come back to that later). In order to do that you'll need to add `observer` on `myValue` only then you'll know when `myValue` has changed.

Above mentioned case had another solution ie listen to `value-changed` event fired by `paper-input`, but what about cases where your property is not binded to any element(its getting its value from db let's say) and you want to know when its value changes.

So to summarise it `two-way binding` is used when you want to know that value of some property which is not part of your own shadow-dom has changed and `observer` is used when you want to know about the changes in properties inside your own dom